# JS Regex - allow double hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below regex to do some validation for user input.

```
^\s{0}$|^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$
```

The user input will be in the format myInvoices--2015Jan12--04-10-11

However, the regex above only allows names with 1 hyphen/dash:  myInvoices-2015Jan12-04-10-11 rather than double dashes.

Can someone tell me how can I allow the user to input double dashes as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\s{0}$|^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-{1,2}){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b-{1,2}){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$
```

I have added `{1,2}` to your `-` to allow one or two dashes

Comment: if you need to allow up to 3 dashes, then it will be `{1,3}` NOT `{1,2,3}` :D just in case

Comment: - and if I would need to allow any number of --, is there something I can use maybe {1,*} for example?

Comment: @user1809790 you can use `-{1,}` or `-+` (it is the same), where `+` means "One or more", if you want make `-{0,}` then you can use `-*` where `*` means "Zero or more", but if you want "two, three or four", then you should write `-{2,4}`

Answer (score 5):

You should just need to add `-?`, i.e. an optional hyphen, after each current hyphen. So `\b-` becomes `\b--?`:

```
^\s{0}$|^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b--?){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|\b--?){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$
```

This matches your sample input